# How can I render custom react component as a plugin in the ckeditor5 toolbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react

I am trying to create custom ckeditor5 plugin in react js, I want to display my own react component in ckeditor5 toolbar.

```js
class Video extends Plugin {
   init() {
      const editor = this.editor

      editor.ui.componentFactory.add('video', VideoButton)
   }
}
```

```js
export function VideoButton() {
   return (
      <>
         <MyOwnComponent />
      </>
   )
}
```

I want to render my own component into the ckeditor5 toolbar. But it is giving me the below error :

```
Argument of type '() => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(locale: Locale) => View<HTMLElement>'.
  Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'View<HTMLElement>': element, isRendered, locale, t, and 22 more.
```

How can I render custom react component as a plugin in the ckeditor5 toolbar?